# NN model format conversion tflite -> onnx

Tags: tensorflow, onnxruntime

I'd like to convert the hosted models [TensorFlow-Lite hosted models](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/hosted_models) mainly the mobilenets into ONNX format. So I'd like to try the quantized version of those hosted models and run them with [onnx-runtime](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime).

What would be the right procedure for converting those models to be consumed by [onnx-runtime](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to ONNX, but according to their official [tutorial page](https://github.com/onnx/tutorials#converting-to-onnx-format), there isn't a TFLite to ONNX converter.

You could still use the TensorFlow -> ONNX conversion path. When you download one of the TFLite hosted models, you'll get an archive, which contains the original TensorFlow frozen graph used for conversion (`xxx_frozen.pb`), as well as the converted `.tflite`. You could take the frozen graph format and feed it into the TensorFlow-ONNX converter as instructed below:

https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

There is a tflite to onnx converter. I have tried this and it has worked for me. I'm not sure about the tensorflow-lite hosted models, but you can give it a try. In my case I used this converter for the models developed by me and it has worked fine.

```
import tflite2onnx

tflite_path = "path/to/the/tflitemodel"
onnx_path = "path/where/you/want/to/save/your/model" #modelname.onnx
tflite2onnx.convert(tflite_path,onnx_path)
```